# Probability that $m$ balls will fall into first box

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

> Suppose we have $n$ balls that are randomly distributed into $N$
> boxes. Find the probability that $m$ balls will fall into the first
> box. Assume that all $N^m$ arrangements are equally likely.

#### Attempt:

First, we notice that for the first box, we have $n$ choices, and for the second box we also have $n$ choices, and so on. Thus, we have $n^N$ ways to place the balls into the boxes. Pick $m$ balls out of the total $n$ balls, that gives ${n \choose m}$. In how many ways can these $m$ balls go into the first box? Well, in just ${1 \choose 1 }= 1 $ ways. Thus,

$$ P = \frac{ {n \choose m } }{n^N } $$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes!, in first like i assume you mean "we notice that for the first ball"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of ways to choose the $m$ items in the first box is $\binom{n}{m}$ and the number of ways to put the remaining $n-m$ items into the remaining $N-1$ boxes is $(N-1)^{n-m}$; therefore, the number of ways to put $m$ items into the first box is
$$
\binom{n}{m}(N-1)^{n-m}
$$
So the probability is
$$
\frac{\binom{n}{m}(N-1)^{n-m}}{N^n}=\frac{\binom{n}{m}}{N^m}\left(1-\frac1N\right)^{n-m}
$$
Note that the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) guarantees that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}(N-1)^{n-m}
&=((N-1)+1)^n\\
&=N^n
\end{align}
$$

Comment: why $N^n$ on the denominator. Isnt it the size of the sample size $n^N$? There are $1,2,3,...,N$ boxes. In the first box we can put $n$ balls, and in the second box we can put also the n balls and the same for the third, fourth, all the way to the $N$ box. So we have $n\times n \times .. \times n = n^N $

Comment: To count the number of ways to put $n$ items into $N$ boxes, the first item has the choice of $N$ boxes, the second item has the choice of $N$ boxes, ..., the $n^\text{th}$ item has the choice of $N$ boxes. That is $\underbrace{N\cdot N\cdots N}_{n\text{ items}}=N^n$.

Comment: I dont understand how this is possible? Why can we not just put all the balls in each box ? Im very confused

Comment: For each possible arrangement of the balls in the boxes, each ball can only be in one box. That is, ball $1$ is in one of the $N$ boxes; ball $2$ is in one of the $N$ boxes; ... ball $n$ is in one of the $N$ boxes. A box can contain multiple balls; a ball cannot be in multiple boxes.

Comment: $n=1,N=3:\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{o|\phantom{o}|\phantom{o}}\ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{\phantom{o}|o|\phantom{o}}\ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{\phantom{o}|\phantom{o}|o}$. This is $N^n=3^1$ outcomes, not $n^N=1^3$.

Comment: I have a doubt if we have 2 balls and 3 boxes, and the balls are equally I only count 6 ways, and you suggest that we have $3^2=9$.

Comment: @BrianPérezGutiérrez: here, there are two balls: $b_1$ and $b_2$ and three containers: $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$. $b_1$ can be in any of the three containers and $b_2$ can be in any of the three containers. We label the balls so that we can compute the probabilities. Two balls in $c_1$ has a $\frac19$ probability and a ball in $c_1$ and a ball in $c_2$ has a $\frac29$ probability. If we just count the arrangements as in stars and bars, it is more difficult to assign probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

If we're just concerned with the first box, and all other boxes are equally likely, it's just a binomial with $n$ trials, for which $p=1/N$.

$$\Pr(m=k) \,=\, {n \choose k}\,p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k} \,=\, {n \choose k}\,N^{-k}\left(1-\frac1N\right)^{n-k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is the number of balls that fall into the first box, then $P(X=m)$ follows the binomial distribution, where $p=1/N$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is different if the balls are indistinguishable. If we have 2 balls and 3 boxes we have 6 ways.

00|  |

|00|

|  |00

0 |0 |

0 |  |0

|0 |0

In this case we have $ \frac{(2+(3-1)!)}{2! (3-1)!}=6 $