# Probability of putting m balls into $N$ compartments.

Tags: probability

> Suppose that $n$ balls are randomly distributed into $N$ compartments.
> Find the probability that $m$ balls will fall into the first
> compartment. Assume that all $N^n$ arrangements are equally likely.

### Attempt.

My idea:  Notice we can place $m$ balls out of the n balls into the first compartment in ${n \choose m}$ ways. Now we want to distribute $n-m$ balls in the remaining $N-1$ compartments.

The first ball can go into any of $N-1$ compartments. So, the second ball can go to any of $N-2$ remaining comparment and so on... so we have in total

$$ (N-1)(N-2)(N-3)...(N-n-m) = \dfrac{(N-1)!}{(N-n-m)!} $$

Therefore, the required probability is

$$ \dfrac{ {n \choose m} \dfrac{(N-1)!}{(N-n-m)!} }{N^n } $$

Now, here is where I get puzzled. The solution key gives answer to be ${n \choose m} (N-1)^{n-m} / N^n $

What am I doing wrong? did I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: This is just a binomial process with success probability $\frac 1n$.  You want exactly $m$ successes.

Comment: Note: in your calculation you appear to believe that, other than the first compartment, each compartment can only hold one ball.  There's nothing in he problem that says that.

Comment: Note:  there's a typo in my first comment,  I meant to write $\frac 1N$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability that $m$ balls will fall into first box](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739130/probability-that-m-balls-will-fall-into-first-box)